# If a sequence converges to $c$, then $c$ is the only limit point of that sequence

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm currently on chapter 6.4 of Analysis I by Terence Tao and am stuck on this proposition which was left as an exercise:

> Let $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n=m}^{\infty}$ be a sequence
> which converges to a real number c. Then c is a limit point of $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n=m}^{\infty}$ and in fact it is the only limit point of $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n=m}^{\infty}$

I was able to show that c was a limit point easily enough but wasn't able to get the second part of the proposition done. I tried setting up a contradiction for using the definition of convergence and using that to show that the two limit points were equal but I wasn't able to make any progress.

Comment: Assume that $b$ is also a limit point. There is a way to show for all $\epsilon >0$, $|b-c|<\epsilon$

Comment: I already managed to show that in my rough work. Didn't realize that I was on the right track- thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c'\ne c$, let $\varepsilon=\frac12|c-c'|$. For some $N\in\Bbb N$, $|c-a_n|<\varepsilon$ whenever $n\geqslant N$. But then, if $n\geqslant N$,$$|c'-a_n|\geqslant\varepsilon=\frac12|c-c'|.$$So, there are only finitely many $n$'s such that $|c'-a_n|<\varepsilon$.